# Chrome Extension Page Action not showing next to omnibar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Manifest:

```
     {
     "manifest_version":2,
     "name":"Optimize url",
     "description":"Optimize url",
     "page_action":{
     "default_icon":{
       "19":"url-icon16.png",
   "38":"url-icon48.png"
 },
 "default_title":"Optimize url"
  },
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "version":"0.1",
  "permissions":[
  "tabs",
  "https://url.com/*"
  ]
 }
```

Background JS:

```
  function checkURL(){
      var host = parseURL(tab.url).host;
    if (host.indexOf("url.com") >= 0) {
     chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
  }
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkURL);
```

Yet when I add it to the developing Extensions page. It doesn't show up anywhere. I was originally going to have this as a browser action but it made more since to use it as a page action since it's only going to be focused for one website only.

Can anyone explain to me what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: 1. You need to specify `tab` in `checkURL`'s definition: `checkURL(`**`tab`**`)` 2. Where is `parseURL` defined ?

Comment: I got this from a tutorial... so It isn't defined I thought maybe it was a chrome* api or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following problems with your code:

1. The variable `tab`, which is used in `checkURL`, is nowhere defined.
2. The function `parseURL` is also nowhere defined (it is not a built-in function as you seem to assume).

It is, also, a good idea to filter the `onUpdated` events looking for `status: 'complete'`, because several `onUpdated` events are triggered during a single tab update.

So, replace your **background.js** code with the following:

```
var hostRegex = /^[^:]+:\/\/[^\/]*url.com/i;
function checkURL(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status === "complete") {
        if (hostRegex.test(tab.url)) {
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        }
    }
}
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkURL);
```