# Page action icon displays only in extension page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning about creating chrome extensions. I have studied about page actions, which is used to create an icon inside the address bar. My code as follows:

In my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version" :2,    
  "name" : "GTmetrix",
  "description": "Test google chrome extension",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "page_action":{
     "default_icon"  : "icon.png",
     "default_popup" : "popup.html",
     "default_title" : "Test Google chrome extension"
  },
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions" : [
     "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

In my `background.js`

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
});
```

In my `popup.html`

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="background.js"></script>-->
        <style>
             body{ background:pink}
            .block{ width : 100%;}
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="block">
            <h2>Test extension</h2>
            <button id="checkpage">Check this page now!!</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I'm using the above code,it shows like below:
[image]

But when I goes to another pages like google or others, it will not show the icon:

[image]

What goes wrong and what is the use of `background` in my `manifest.json` and why we are using `content_script`, what is the exact meaning of that?

I have looked through [the devguide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide)

Comment: Please don't use backticks (\`) to highlight normal text. They are for inline code.

Comment: this may also help i think [Refer](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: It's not a bad one; up to date, at least.

Comment: @Xan sorry....what are you coming to say?

Comment: Commenting on your tutorial link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following in background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, info, tab){
    showPageAction(tab);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(id, info, tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true },
        function (tabArray) {
            if(tabArray[0]){
                showPageAction(tabArray[0]);
            }
        });
});

function showPageAction(tab){
    chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id)
}
```

There are other methods too. [Chrome Extension samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:pageaction)

PS:

1. Before showing you can check tab URL or something as criteria.
2. don't user page action if applicable to all tabs - use browser action instead.

Comment: great!!it works...but it shows for all the pages...how do i restrict for a specific pages? for example i want to restrict this extension from google...

Comment: showPageAction(tab) -> tab is an object of https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab. usually tab.url is used to restrict it to certain domains.

Comment: can you please explain this answer:(

Comment: I have referred [Link-for display on specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902247/display-page-action-icon-on-specific-url) in that i dnt the meaning of `~tab.url.indexOf('.pl')`?Can someone explain me?

Comment: tab.url -> string containing URL -> indexOf() string function -> find index of "p1" in url.

Answer (score 2):

### So, you're starting to learn Chrome extensions..

You looked at the Devguide page.

What you absolutely must look at is the [Overview page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), especially the architecture part. It explains what [different scripts (background, content, popup) do and how they interact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28998352/934239).

For example, content scripts are needed when you need to interact with the *content* of an open tab.

### Why doesn't your extension work?

The background script loads at the moment your extension is loaded. So, your code executes:

```
// Grab the currently active tab
// (this is deprecated by the way, tabs.query is the modern way)
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  // Show the button on that tab
  chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
});
```

It works, quite perfectly, from your screenshots.

And after that, your background script is *done*. There's nothing left to do for it, and it will not do anything. And, as Page Actions require to be told to show up, you'll never see the icon again.

### So how to make it work?

Well, your background page is normally a central dispatch for various events. You need to tell Chrome you want to react to something by registering [an event handler](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events).

Amit G [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31180030/934239) proposes a series of [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) events to "hook" into. Personally, I would cover `onUpdated`, `onCreated` and `onReplaced` events to catch all page changes.

### Are event handlers the only way?

**In many cases, yes**, but showing a page action is lucky. It is supported by [`declarativeContent` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent), that allows you to set rules for when it should appear and let Chrome take care of the rest.

The docs have plenty of good examples.

### That seems like a lot of work for showing an icon!

Well, yes, because Page Actions are supposed to be triggered by some condition.

From [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction):

> If you want the extension's icon to always be visible, use a browser action instead.

So unless you need to show an icon only on *some* pages, use [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!! i will learn from your answer and if i have any doubts will ask u....

Comment: I have referred [Link-for display on specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902247/display-page-action-icon-on-specific-url) in that i dnt the meaning of `~tab.url.indexOf('.pl')`?Can someone explain me?

Comment: Not here. It's not a forum, you shouldn't ask follow-up questions in answers. And I'm sure it's answered already, search SO.